# Kotlin: best practice for parallel nullable / null safe trait or interface?

Tags: kotlin

Consider the following simple trait:

```
trait HasAge {
    val dateOfBirth: LocalDate
    val age: Int
        get() = ...
}
```

Now assume that I have a person class like so:

```
class Person : HasAge {
    ...
    public override var dateOfBirth: LocalDate? = null
}
```

If I build a library and I want to cater for both nullable and null-safe users, I'll end up with duplicates like these:

```
trait HasAge {
    val dateOfBirth: LocalDate
    val age: Int
        get() = ...
}

trait HasAgeN {
    val dateOfBirth: LocalDate?
    val age: Int?
        get() = ...
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? i.e a trait or library function that can handle both cases without duplicating everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend one trait with the other, overriding the types:

```
trait HasAgeN {
  val date: LocalDate?
  val age: Int?
      get() = ...
}

trait HasAge : HasAgeN {
  override val date: LocalDate
  override val age: Int
      get() = ...
}
```

Now, a function that takes `HasAgeN` can accept both traits

Comment: So that helps a little but I'd still need to duplicate the whole trait. Plus this feels icky. How come Kotlin allows you to change the type in a subclass?

Comment: @AmirAbiri, you can read about covariant return types [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type).